# Problem with 'feyn' package for 11pt font size

Tags: fonts, errors, fontsize, compiling

I need to draw several Feynman diagrams and I found the feyn package suitable enough for this purpose. I use MiKTeX to compile the tex-file. The problem is that for some *strange* reason it does not accept 11 pt font-size? I say *strange*, because the 10pt and 12pt versions are perfectly executable, and the difference between them and the 11pt-module is just in the values of some arguments (arrow width, loop radius, etc.), which shouldn't cause any compilation problems...

The exact mistake description, which I get, is:

```
! I can't find file `cmr11'.

l.33 input cmr11

            ;^^I^^I^^I% ...but miss out the `generate roman'

Please type another input file name

! Emergency stop.

l.33 input cmr11

            ;^^I^^I^^I% ...but miss out the `generate roman'

Transcript written on feyn11.log.

miktex-maketfm.exe: Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
miktex-maketfm.exe: Data: feyn11.tfm
! Font OMS/feyn/m/n/10.95=feyn11 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
  found.
<to be read again> 
               relax 

 l.99 \setbox0=\hbox{$\FeynSpaceChar$}
?
```

Here is an example with the (working) 12pt font-size:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage{feyn}
\begin{document}
    $\Diagram{ fdA & & fuA \\ & g & \\ fuA && fdA }$
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample 12pt diagram]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please put that document in the question, not in comments

Comment: The example in the above (now deleted?) comment works without error in texlive 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is `feyn11.mf`:

```
% Feynman diagram font, 11pt display size, release 0.3.3, 2009 October 8.
%
% Copyright 1991, 1994, 2001, Norman Gray <norman@astro.gla.ac.uk>
% Mercurial revision 204fc9a2e560, 2009-10-08 12:56 +0100

font_identifier "FEYN"; font_size 11pt#;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First the base size

module# := 11pt#;

% phfudge is ... what?!
phfudge# := 0pt#;       % must be, for \Diagram macro

linewidth# := 0.85pt#;      % pen width
thinlinewidth# := 0.55pt#;  % thin pen
bigarrow# := 6.5pt#;        % size of arrows
littlearrow# := 4.5pt#;
blobr# := 7pt#;         % radius of blobs and crosses

on_math_axis := 1;

% We want the roman digits from the corresponding cmr font, and that's
% all.  Therefore, we don't want to obey the `generate' command in
% cmr??.mf.  To do this, we read in cmbase, and then set generate to
% gobble its argument. 
def gobble primary g=enddef;    % gobbles its argument
input cmbase;           % Read it explicitly, rather than
                % implicitly within cmr10
let generate=gobble;
input cmr11;            % ...but miss out the `generate roman'

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% To business....

input feyn;

end
```

There is ***no*** `cmr11.mf` file in the standard distribution of the Computer Modern fonts, so running Metafont on this file will result in the error

```
! I can't find file `cmr11'.

l.33 input cmr11
```

unless the `sauter` package is installed too, which is able to supply interpolated versions of the files in the Computer Modern font distribution.

For MiKTeX the package is listed at http://miktex.org/packages/sauter so it can be installed with the wizard. For TeX Live it is

```
tlmgr install sauter
```

Comment: This was the problem, indeed. I should point out, though, that the installation of `sauter` didn't help. Nevertheless, I simply edited the `feyn11.mf` and `feyntext11.mf` files and made them load `cmr10` (instead of `cmr11`), which resolved the problem. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @NewbieTexnician I don't know what happens on MiKTeX, sorry.

Comment: @NewbieTexnician: That looks like an error that should be reported to the author (Norman Gray).

Comment: @MartinSchröder I believe it's deliberate, but of course it assumes `cmr11.mf` exists or can be generated. Actually, the instruction `input cmr11` after `let generate=gobble` just collects the parameters, which could be obtained in a different way, in this case.